# variadic templates - ambiguous call

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

The following code compiles in both gcc 4.7.2 and MSVC-11.0:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T bar) {}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void foo(T bar, Args... args) {}

int main()
{
    foo(0); // OK
}
```

Why? I think that it's must be ambiguous call:

**ISO/IEC 14882:2011**

> 14.5.6.2 Partial ordering of function templates [temp.func.order]

5 ...

```
[ Example:

template<class T, class... U> void f(T, U...); // #1

template<class T > void f(T); // #2

template<class T, class... U> void g(T*, U...); // #3

template<class T > void g(T); // #4

void h(int i) {

f(&i); // error: ambiguous

g(&i); // OK: calls #3

}

—end example ]
```

Comment: This is the final version of C++11 standard, not draft

Comment: @Nawaz: What do you think (s)he missed?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm just guessing (may-be, could-be sort of guess). I don't claim he missed something.

Comment: @Nawaz: Okay. I thought that when you said "you missed something" you were claiming that (s)he missed something.

Answer (score 13):

[This is considered a defect in the current standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1395). Even the standard itself relies on non-variadic templates to be partially ordered before variadic ones in the specification of `std::common_type`:

`§20.9.7.6 [meta.trans.other] p3`

> The nested typedef `common_type::type` shall be defined as follows:

```
template <class ...T> struct common_type;

template <class T>
struct common_type<T> {
  typedef T type;
};

template <class T, class U>
struct common_type<T, U> {
  typedef decltype(true ? declval<T>() : declval<U>()) type;
};

template <class T, class U, class... V>
struct common_type<T, U, V...> {
  typedef typename common_type<typename common_type<T, U>::type, V...>::type type;
};
```

Specifically `common_type<T, U>` vs `common_type<T, U, V...>`.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you're right! That's a compiler "feature", and quite possibly a *deliberate* one since the committee has suggested, in [issue #1395](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1395), that this case [*should* be accepted](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/EHIBDm43faM) and, as such, it seems likely that in future standards (or even a TR) it *will* be.