# Should partial specialization of variadic template classes favor non-variadic specializations

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I wonder whether the classic recursive pattern for building for instance a tuple should work with one regular template parameter or if two are required. Here is the one-parameter case:

```
// Forward declaration of main tuple class template.
template<typename... Ds> class Tuple;

// Tuple class specialization for the general case
template<typename D, typename... Ds> class Tuple<D, Ds...> {
public:

    typedef D HeadType;
    typedef Tuple<Ds...> TailType;

    Tuple() {}

    Tuple(const D& head, const Ds&... ds) : mHead(head), mTail(ds...) {}

    HeadType mHead;
    TailType mTail;
};

// Sentinel one element case
template<typename D> class Tuple<D> {
public:
    typedef D HeadType;

    Tuple() {}
    Tuple(const D& d) : mHead(d) {}

    HeadType mHead;
};
```

Here you could argue that when instantiated (directly or in the recursion) with one template parameter: `Tuple<int>` that both specializations are valid and the declaration should be ambiguous. However, VS2012 Nov CTP accepts this code, so I don't know if it is ok or if the compiler is just being nice. I have not been able to find any passage in the standard text that mentions this case, but it is surely convenient that it compiles, and to some extent logical that the "more specific" non-variadic specialization wins.

Now, if this is not proper C++11 the code below is an alternative, using two regular template parameters so that the 1 parameter case can not select the general specialization:

```
// Forward declaration of main tuple class template.
template<typename... Ds> class Tuple;

// Tuple class specialization for the general case
template<typename D, typename D2, typename... Ds> class Tuple<D, D2, Ds...> {
public:

    typedef D HeadType;
    typedef Tuple<D2, Ds...> TailType;

    Tuple() {}

    Tuple(const D& head, const D2& d2, const Ds&... ds) : mHead(head), mTail(d2, ds...) {}

    HeadType mHead;
    TailType mTail;
};

// Sentinel one element case
template<typename D> class Tuple<D> {
public:
    typedef D HeadType;

    Tuple() {}
    Tuple(const D& d) : mHead(d) {}

    HeadType mHead;
};
```

This, sadly, does not compile on VS2012 Nov CTP, but that is surely a bug: The ctor call to mTail does not understand that an empty parameter pack is empty when the first specialization is called with two types...

So the main question is still: Is the first version valid C++?

If someone can pinpoint an error on my part in the second alternative, please do!

Answer (score 5):

> Here you could argue that when instantiated (directly or in the recursion) with one template parameter: `Tuple<int>` that both specializations are valid and the declaration should be ambiguous.

According to the current standard, yes, this should indeed be ambiguous. See [this defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1395). However, the committee says for non-variadic variants to be ranked better than variadic ones and even *relies* on that in the current standard. I'll just conveniently link [to another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14005158/500104) which contains an example.

Now, basically all good compilers already implement the resolution of this DR, and they have to, since otherwise `std::common_type` would be simply broken (if defined as specified). So yeah, in a sense the compiler is being nice to you, but for a good reason.

> This, sadly, does not compile on VS2012 Nov CTP, but that is surely a bug

Yes, this is a bug, and the November CTP is known to be *extremely* buggy. When I played around with it, I filed 11 variadic bugs that night (plus 3 decltype bugs, I think).

Comment: +1 for the first part, I didn't realize that it is currently ambiguous. In fact, the last example in 14.5.6.2/5 shows just that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specialize the empty tuple version? Im my implementations of type lists, i alwways do that:

```
template<typename... T> 
struct Tuple;

template<typename HEAD , typename... TAIL>
struct Tuple<HEAD,TAIL...>
{
    using mHead = HEAD;
    using mTail = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(TAIL) > 0,Tuple<TAIL...>>::type;

    ...
};

template<>
struct Tuple<>
{
    static_assert(false , "Empty tuples are not valid tuples");
};
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't show the quite obvious zero-parameter case. What is more interesting with your answer is the enable_if usage to handle the 1 parameter case without resorting to a template overload. However, I'm curious what the type mTail is in the one parameter (empty TAIL) case. You don't show the data member holding the tail, and I know that you are (sadly) not allowed to declare data members of type void. -- I tried that, which would have been convenient.