# Why is this variadic function call ambiguous?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
  template<typename FilterComponent, typename ...FilterComponents>
  std::bitset<components_count> component_impl(std::bitset<components_count> &b){
    b.set(FilterComponent::get_id());
    return component_impl<FilterComponents...>(b); //ambiguous
  }
  template<typename FilterComponent>
  std::bitset<components_count> component_impl(std::bitset<components_count> &b){
    b.set(FilterComponent::get_id());
    return b;
  }
  template<typename ...FilterComponents>
  std::bitset<components_count> component_mask(){
    std::bitset<components_count> b;
    component_impl<FilterComponents...>(b);
    return b;
  }
```

Why is this function call ambiguous? I wanted to call it like `component_mask<Foo,Bar,Baz>();`

```
error: call to member function 'component_impl' is ambiguous
    return component_impl<FilterComponents...>(b);
```

Comment: Testcase please...... Why do I have to ask for a testcase on every question? Why is it so hard to comprehend its importance? And why is nobody constructing them _before_ posting on the internet?! Auch!!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Okay give me one moment.

Comment: When `FilterComponents` has only one element, both function templates can be instantiated with the exact same template arguments.

Comment: Usually partial ordering will save you, but not in this case since your template parameters are not in the function parameters' types.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6469a80870492cf

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's why questions should include the **complete** error message.  Of course, looking at the complete message, the question probably wouldn't have been needed.  IDEs do a tremendous disservice by offering an "error list" window that truncates the error information at the first linebreak.

Comment: Also dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14005020/103167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `component_impl` is called with one typename, it is ambiguous. The first version matches with an empty typename pack. The second version also is a match.

Change the variadic template version to have two typenames before the typename pack. That will disambiguate the two functions.

```
template<typename FilterComponent1, typename FilterComponent2, typename ...FilterComponents>
std::bitset<components_count> component_impl(std::bitset<components_count> &b){
   b.set(FilterComponent1::get_id());
   return component_impl<FilterComponent2, FilterComponents...>(b);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When `FilterComponents...` is empty or has only one element, there is an ambiguity because both function templates are equally viable. You can add a second template argument to the first template declaration to resolve the ambiguity (like [R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27682105/701092) does). You can also unpack the arguments into an initializer-list to get the same effect:

```c++
template<typename... FilterComponents>
std::bitset<components_count> component_impl(std::bitset<components_count>& b)
{
    using discard = int[];
    (void)discard{ 0, (b.set(FilterComponents::get()), void(), 0)... };
    return b;
}
```

The first `0` and trailing `0` is to compensate for an empty parameter pack and to fill the the list with integers thus discarding the `void()` type. The `void()` "erases" the return value of `set()` thereby preventing the possible use of an overload `operator,()` from its return type (for which we know `std::bitset::set()` doesn't have but when you're dealing with a general case it's helpful to use it).

This also removes the need for a second overload to help with recursion.

Comment: I guess it removes the need for a separate helper function at all.

Comment: Good solution. An explanation of those `0` and `void()` wouldn't go amiss!

Comment: The first 0 should go outside the pack expansion.

Comment: The `void()` you took out indeed isn't necessary here, but it was a good general tip that I thought was nice of you to include: it made sure the built-in `,` was used regardless of how `b.set` was declared, as no custom `operator,` can take a parameter of type `void`. It's not necessary here since `b.set`'s return type is known not to have any overloaded `operator,`, but it is useful if this answer is extended to call other methods returning other types.

Comment: @hvd Thanks, I will add it back in.